# Android Studio keeps refreshing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

My Android Studio keeps refreshing the project directory, like an infinite loop, I can't do anything.

[image]
[image]

I open a project with multiple modules and it will happen often. Only one module project has not encountered this situation.

My Android Studio info:

```
Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 5, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

[image]